# Column alignment issue with fixed header data table

Tags: angularjs, datatable, fixed-header-tables

I am using fixed header property for the angular data table and the code look like as follows

```
$scope.table.dataTable($scope.gridOpts);    
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader($scope.table);
```

The header of the table became fixed at the top of the page while scrolling, and everything worked fine. But I faced column alignment issue between the header columns and body columns of  data table.

So I tried the solution described in http://bobcravens.com/2010/01/html-scrolling-table-with-fixed-headers-jquery-plugin/, but the result remains same.

I couldn't understand why this happens. So I given some timeout on calling the fixed header functionality `new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader($scope.table);`. But the result again remains same.

Any body faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, the problem is a simple one. The data table fixed header functionality is cloning the table header and appending to the body. But the trap is, the classes given to the original table head will not be available in the cloned table, if the styles are defined by referring some parent class. So if we gave some font sizes to the table head will not reflect in cloned header and hence the column alignment will be broken!.

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Comment: what is exactly $scope.table ? can u post your entire code in angular js?

Comment: $scope.table is simply the DOM element.

Comment: u mean it is the "id" of the table? Sorry but i didnt get u..can you please share your code snippet for fixing of header of table that is working for u

Comment: $scope.table = angular.element(document.querySelector("#table-id")); $scope.table.dataTable(gridOpts); new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader($scope.table); Hope, this will helps u..

Comment: I am getting a error "gridOpts is not defined" ..can you please tell me what is gridOpts through code